# How to convert integer to its equivalent string in python?

Tags: python

I want to convert `100` to `One Hundred` or any number to its equivalent string.

I want to avoid writing a lengthy program. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Write some code, test it, fix what doesn't work, repeat until successful.  That will probably be the best way to do it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a package like `humanize` : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize

```
>>> import humanize
>>> humanize.intcomma(12345)
'12,345'
>>> humanize.intword(123455913)
'123.5 million'
>>> humanize.intword(12345591313)
'12.3 billion'
>>> humanize.apnumber(4)
'four'
>>> humanize.apnumber(41)
'41'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [humanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize)

```
>>> import humanize
>>> humanize.intword(100)
'One Hundred'
```

Also you may try to use  [pynum2word](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pynum2word/)

```
>>> import num2word
>>> num2word.to_card(15)
'fifteen'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the inflect library in python.

I simply did,

```
    import inflect

    i = inflect.engine()
    print i.number_to_words(number)
```

Rest of the answers are better but this works best for me.